# How to say “to light a candle"

Tags: vocabulary, word-requests

I'm trying to figure out the most appropriate way to say "light a candle" would it be 点蜡烛  or would 点燃蜡烛 be more commonly heard?

Comment: Both can be OK. The 2nd way is more normal.

Comment: 点蜡烛 - light a candle; 点燃蜡烛 - light _up_ a candle

Answer (score 6):

I think 点蜡烛 is more common as it is more used in daily speaking. 点燃蜡烛 is more formal to me and sounds like written Chinese.

I come from HK so I am not sure the usage in other places.

Comment: You can also say 點著蠟燭 [diǎnzháo làzhú] (to light a candle).

Comment: The 著 in 點著蠟燭 means "already", which makes the whole thing "lit a candle / some candles already", so use this phrase depends on the context.

Comment: ^ That's only one of the meanings. Of course you can say 去點著蠟燭 "Go light some candles already". In that case, the candles are not lit. So, depends.

Answer (score 1):

点蜡烛is an imperative sentence
I like to say 点一下蜡烛，if I ask someone to light the candle.

Answer (score 0):

点燃 is sth seems more like *light ... to make it burn*. And since candles will not literally be **on fire** (燃), it is improper to say so.

The structure is like "I **knock**-ed him **unconscious**." (我 **打晕** 了他。). Literally "I hit him to make him faint".

Answer (score 0):

点蜡烛 is more common.

点 means "to light", 燃 means "to light/ burn".

We need efficient communication in daily life, therefore, 点蜡烛 is okay.